# Barcode Scan with Python

Tags: python, barcode, zbar

What I want to do is to capture the barcode of some products from a webcam or from a USB barcode reader but I don't have any clue where to begin with.

In my case, user would scan a barcode and based on the barcode something will happen, like the browser will display a picture of the product.

I have heard about Zbar, but looked at some information on Youtube and other places but all I found was already built products in use.

Could someone help me on it?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played with it much, but zbar seems to work ok, as long as the barcodes (including QR codes) are of reasonable quality. IIRC, I got zbar-tools and python-zbar from the Debian repos.

The zbar python documentation is pretty minimal, but there are two example programs at [SourceArchive](http://zbar.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.10plus-pdoc-2/dir_a0486103f0c3d8960b37f5b09cfacaf3.html), one for scanning barcodes from /dev/video (i.e. a Video4Linux device) and one for scanning from an image file; the image file is read using the ImageMagick library, so it can handle a very wide range of image file formats.

I don't have a scanner, webcam, etc, so I've only tested zbar with image files. It tries to find & decode everything in the image that looks like a barcode, and it doesn't mind if the barcodes aren't aligned nicely or are a little bit noisy.